# MSSQL server 2013 Built in method which Returns the location point of the Earth given its latitude and longitude

Tags: sql-server, django, postgresql

> I'm new in MSSQL server, I've changed my db from postgres to mssql
>   server 2013. Prior I have used raw query in my Django(python)
>   application and after changing my db to mssql, the buit in function of
>   postgres does not exits in mssql sevrer. So is there any buitin
>   function in mssql server similar to ll_to_earth and earth_distance.
>
> My GenericViewSet in django, in which I have added raw query with ORM

```
def list(self, request):
    '''docstring'''
    params = request.data
    distance_range = params['range'] * 1609.34 if 'range' in params and params['range'] else 2 * 1609.34
    queryset = ValetAt.objects.raw('''
        SELECT valetat.id, earth_distance(ll_to_earth({},{}), ll_to_earth(valetat.latitude, valetat.longitude)) as distance FROM valetat WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth({},{}),{}) @> ll_to_earth(valetat.latitude, valetat.longitude) ORDER BY distance ASC;
    '''.format(params["latitude"], params["longitude"], params["latitude"], params["longitude"], distance_range))
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322924/how-to-store-longitute-latitude-as-a-geography-in-sql-server-2014

Answer (score 0):

> To solve my problem using store procedure, I have created a stored
>   procedure in db and then execute it in my django code, that solve my
>   problem.

```
def list(self, request):
    params = request.data
    dist_range = param['range'] * 1609.34 if 'range' in params and params['range'] else 2 * 1609.34
    que = User.objects.raw('''execute calDistanceEx @RADIUS = {}, @LAT = {}, @LONG = {}, @USER_ID={}, @GEO1 = NULL;'''.format(dist_range , params["lat"], params["long"], userId))
    serializer = self.get_serializer(que, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```